# Exact matching string with "==" operator between Str and a list of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string, list

I have this example df:

```
df6 = pd.DataFrame({
                   'answer1': ['Lo', 'New York', 'Toronto'],
                   'answer2': ['London', 'New', 'Paris'],
                   'answer3': ['CA', 'CA', 'CA'],
                   'correct': [['London'], ['New York'], ['Toronto']]
                   })

df6
```

gives:

```
    answer1   answer2     answer3     correct
0   Lo         London         CA    [London]
1   New York    New           CA    [New York]
2   Toronto    Paris          CA    [Toronto]
```

I am trying to get the column name (answer 1 or 2 .. etc) that contains the text in the correct column in a new column called `Answer` by matching values in `str` format. The correct column has the data in a list type

I used the following code to do so:

```
cols = df6.filter(like='answer').columns

df6['Answer'] = df6[cols].apply(lambda s: ', '.join(cols[(m:=[str(s[col]) in str(df6.loc[s.name, 'correct']) for col in cols])]) , axis=1)
```

But I go inaccurate results:

```
    answer1    answer2     answer3     correct       Answer
0   Lo         London       CA         [London]      answer1, answer2
1   New York   New          CA         [New York]    answer1, answer2
2   Toronto    Paris        CA         [Toronto]     answer1
```

It should be:

```
    answer1    answer2     answer3     correct       Answer
0   Lo         London       CA         [London]      answer2
1   New York   New          CA         [New York]    answer1
2   Toronto    Paris        CA         [Toronto]     answer1
```

If I changed `in` to `==` the code will not work because the type of data is not comparable (str with list) and also I need to wrap list items in a `str` to avoid multiple data issues in my original df

I do not know how to achieve this?

---

**Edit:**

So to make it a bit short, for this line of code:

```
df6['Answer'] = df6[cols].apply(lambda s: ', '.join(cols[(m:=[str(s[col]) in str(df6.loc[s.name, 'correct']) for col in cols])]) , axis=1)
```

this particular part in the above line:

```
str(s[col]) in str(df6.loc[s.name, 'correct'])
```

I need to find a way to check the exact match to use `==` instead of `in`. It is like looping through list of strings

I tried to play with it but with no result:

```
 str(s[col]) == [x for x in str(df6.loc[s.name, 'correct'])]
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Strip correct of corner brackets , check existence in df and then conditionally copy over the columns

```
 df6['answer'] =df6.isin(df6['correct'].str[0].to_list()).agg(lambda s: s.index[s].values, axis=1)
df6



     answer1 answer2 answer3     correct     answer
0        Lo  London      CA    [London]  [answer2]
1  New York     New      CA  [New York]  [answer1]
2   Toronto   Paris      CA   [Toronto]  [answer1]
```

Comment: Thanks wwnde, it works perfectly but the correct column sometimes may have more than one matching value. `df6 = pd.DataFrame({
                   'answer1': ['Lo', 'New York', 'Toronto'],
                   'answer2': ['London', 'New', 'Paris'],
                   'answer3': ['CA', 'CA', 'CA'],
                   'correct': [["'London'","'CA'"], ['New York'], ['Toronto']]
                   })`

Comment: something like this? `df6.isin(df6['correct'].explode().str.replace('[^\w]','', regex=True).to_list()).agg(lambda s: s.index[s].values, axis=1)`

Comment: it gives the right results for the first row only but inaccurate matching for the other two rows.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look if the element in the `answer` column is in the list, not in the string, in the `correct` column:

```
df6['Answer'] = df6[cols].apply(lambda s: ', '.join(cols[(m:=[str(s[col]) in list(df6.loc[s.name, 'correct']) for col in cols])]) , axis=1)
```

Should work, as this is checking if the `answerX` element is in the `correct` list.

Comment: yes it works by checking it the element is in the correct list, but it is not giving the exact match. See the output of the first two rows.

Comment: it is now, check the ouput of this code